# Querying geography data type from different servers

Tags: sql-server, sqlgeography

I'm on `server1`, it has a lot of dbs. I need to be able to query (select) geography type from different dbs specified. This works fine

```
SELECT GeoField=geography::STGeomFromText(GeoField,4326)
FROM 
(SELECT convert(nvarchar(max),GeoField) as GeoField from [server1].dbA.dbo.MyTable) as t
```

Now I need to query from `server1`, `servers2` db. `server2` is linked on `server1`. I can use this query which works fine

```
SELECT GeoField=geography::STGeomFromText(GeoField,4326)
FROM OPENQUERY([server2],
'SELECT GeoField=convert(nvarchar(max),GeoField) from dbB.dbo.MyTable')
```

All queries are run from `server1`. Constraint: I can't add `server1` as a linked server on `server1`.

**Question**: how can I use one query to query both my current server (server1) and linked server (server2) by simply changing servername and dbname, and not use two different queries specified above?

Comment: Have you tried `SELECT GeoField=geography::STGeomFromText(GeoField,4326)
FROM 
(SELECT convert(nvarchar(max),GeoField) as GeoField from server2.dbB.dbo.MyTable'`?

Comment: Sure thing, it says geography type cna't be queried that way

Comment: Weird. What is the error message?

Comment: Objects exposing columns with CLR types are not allowed in distributed queries. Please use a pass-through query to access remote object

Comment: Ah. Interesting. Try selecting the remote nvarchar column into a local temp table and then so the conversation to geography from there. Out of curiosity, what days type is GeoField natively? Doing two conversions is weird to me.